# What is Different Between "MFC DLL" and "Console Application DLL"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

What is the difference between creating a MFC DLL from Visual Studio wizard and creating C++ Console Application and changing the configuration type to DLL instead of .exe?

[image: Console Application DLL]

Comment: My guess is that MFC is for creating windowing applications, and the other is for creating console applications.

Comment: @tho You're guessing wrong. There is no fundamental difference between applications targeting the CONSOLE subsystem and those targeting the WINDOWS subsystem. Either one has access to the same Win32 API surface. While MFC is frequently used to implement applications with a GUI, there are lots of non-GUI facilities in MFC (such as `CAsyncSocket` or `CWinThread`). Besides, this question is asking about DLLs, libraries, so this isn't even about applications.

Comment: So this means that when I build a console function without windowing features, the compiler will link in the MFC DLL?

Comment: @tho I don't know what *"when I build a console function"* means. *"the compiler will link"* - Er, no. The compiler translates source code into object code. It doesn't link anything. That's the linker's job. The linker *"will link in the MFC DLL?"*. If you instruct the linker to do so, that's what it will do. If you don't then it won't. It's not like the linker would spontaneously develop a live of its own and link against random libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely figure out how to change a console application to dll type, but it's recommended to use the non-MFC DLL project template.

One major difference between a non-MFC and a MFC Extension DLL is that it would allow sharing resources like dialog templates or bitmaps to MFC appliactions by calling

```
  // MFC extension DLL one-time initialization
  AfxInitExtensionModule(PROJNAMEDLL, hInstance);

  // Insert this DLL into the resource chain
  new CDynLinkLibrary(Dll3DLL);
```

in `DllMain()`. Other benefits are that you can use MFC (`CObject`-derived) classes that sit in the dll and that the MFC Extension DLL can share the memory address space with the calling instance, meaning that two apps loading the same extension DLL will only share the code but won't interfere with allocated data.

Note that you need the "shared MFC DLL" project setting to use extension DLLs. Linking MFC statically into your project won't work. So extension DLLs aim at sharing code among different apps that run simultaneously, for example, but only use the code memory once. This way of code reuse was one intention at least when extension DLLs were introduced, but in the real world different apps tend to use different versions (dll hell, side-by-side). Speaking of:
One good use of an extension DLL is to customize an app (branding, localisation) just by installing differend versions of a dll.

Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/extension-dlls

Comment: *"Other benefits are that you can use MFC (CObject-derived) classes that sit in the dll and that the MFC Extension DLL can share the memory address space with the calling instance, meaning that two apps loading the same extension DLL will only share the code but won't interfere with allocated data."* - That's a property of a process using a virtual address space. This has nothing to do with DLLs and certainly nothing with MFC. *"This way of code reuse was one intention at least when extension DLLs were introduced"* - This has nothing to do with MFC Extension DLLs.

Comment: Seems like you have a very unique understanding of what an MFC Extension DLL is, that does not coincide with what it *actually* is. Some of the specific properties are explained in the link you provided. Specifically, an MFC Extension DLL shares the same allocator with the application it is loaded into, meaning that objects can freely cross its DLL boundary (which they [usually cannot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries)). Every benefit you attribute to MFC Extension DLLs is a property of *any* DLL.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Creating an MFC DLL Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/creating-an-mfc-dll-project?view=msvc-170) it states:

> An MFC DLL is a binary file that acts as a shared library of functions that can be used simultaneously by multiple applications. The easiest way to create an MFC DLL project is to use the MFC DLL Wizard.

This article [Kinds of DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/kinds-of-dlls?view=msvc-170) also states:

> Using Visual Studio, you can build Win32 DLLs in C or C++ that do not
> use the Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) library. You can create a
> non-MFC DLL project with the Win32 Application Wizard.
>
> The MFC library itself is available, in either static link libraries
> or in a number of DLLs, with the MFC DLL Wizard. If your DLL is using
> MFC, Visual Studio supports three different DLL development scenarios ...

I believe the above explains the difference:

- One version of the DLL exposes the MFC library.
- One version does not.

That is my understanding.

---

Other related article: [Create C/C++ DLLs in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/dlls-in-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 0):

An MFC DLL is a dynamic library that uses MFC components and the MFC runtime. This means that an MFC dynamic library usually requires the MFC support libraries along with the MFC runtime. To compile an MFC DLL requires the MFC include files and the MFC directives.

When you use the Visual Studio Wizard to create an MFC DLL all the compiler, linker, and other settings and options needed to create an MFC DLL are all generated for you along with an MFC DLL stub.

A Console Application is an application that uses the C++ Runtime from a console window.

When you use the Visual Studio Wizard to create a Console Application all the compiler, linker, and other settings and options to create a Console Application are all generated for you with a Console Application stub which is typically a Hello World type of application with a `main()` that contains a `printf()`.

The source code for a DLL has required structure for a DLL main entry point that is different from the required structure for a Console Application main entry point. See the Microsoft article [DllMain entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) which has this example source code:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  // handle to DLL module
    DWORD fdwReason,     // reason for calling function
    LPVOID lpReserved )  // reserved
{
    // Perform actions based on the reason for calling.
    switch( fdwReason ) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         // Initialize once for each new process.
         // Return FALSE to fail DLL load.
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
         // Do thread-specific initialization.
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
         // Do thread-specific cleanup.
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
         // Perform any necessary cleanup.
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;  // Successful DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.
}
```

So the differences between an MFC DLL and a Console Application involves a number of areas:

- the structure of the source code
- the include files used in the compile
- the libraries used in the link
- the options used in the compile
- the options used in the link

Changing the configuration type does not modify the source code or include files specified in the source code. Nor does changing the configuration type change all of the necessary compiler and linker options and property settings that need to be changed.

See this Microsoft article, [DLLs and Visual C++ run-time library behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior?view=msvc-170), that discusses the structure of DLLs and their run time behavior which provides an idea as to the differences between an EXE and a DLL.

Answer (score -1):

An Application (executable) is a module that can be run. It contains one entrypoint, the `main()` (console) or `WinMain()` (windows GUI) function. A running instance of an executable is called a **"process"** in Win32.

A DLL is a library, intended for use by other applications. It is loaded at runtime - "dynamically", hence the name. DLLs contain no main entrypoint, instead they "export" functions or even classes and data. Lacking a main entrypoint, DLLs cannot be run stand-alone, instead they are **"loaded into a process's (application's) address-space"**. The process can use their exported items. It is a good way to implement commonly used operations, for example a company's "development environment" or "foundation" - SDKs are typically implemented as DLLs.

MFC is a C++ library containing GUI (and other) classes and functions, largely (but not exclusively) wrapping Win32 objects. An application or DLL can be using the MFC library, or not.

As for your question, creating a console application and then changing it to DLL makes no sense. The Wizard will create a `main()` function, which you will have to manually remove. And finally you will have what, a normal DLL... You can simply create a DLL from the start, whether it will be using MFC or not.

---

### **EDIT:**

According to the [**documentation from Microsoft**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/about-processes-and-threads):

*Each process provides the resources needed to execute a program. A process has a virtual address space, executable code, open handles to system objects, a security context, a unique process identifier, environment variables, a priority class, minimum and maximum working set sizes, **and at least one thread of execution**. Each process is started with a single thread, often called the primary thread, but can create additional threads from any of its threads.*

So yes, processes **need** to contain at least one thread - terminating the primary thread also terminates the process. Furthermore, an executable **must** contain an entry point, it's what the primary thread will execute and return a value to the system. It's actually impossible to build an executable without a `main()/WinMain()` function, it will generate [**Linker Error LNK1561**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1561?view=msvc-170):

*entry point must be defined*

*The linker did not find an entry point, the initial function to call in your executable. By default, the linker looks for a main or wmain function for a console app, a WinMain or wWinMain function for a Windows app, or DllMain for a DLL that requires initialization. You can specify another function by using the /ENTRY linker option.*

As for DLLs, the term dynamic "linking" is indeed used by MS, however only to highlight the differences to static linking (what most developers consider linking). It's not linking in the usual way, ie resolving externals, changing symbol names to addresses, performing fixups and the like. A DLL has no unresolved externals and the so called "linking" means just locating exported items from the loaded DLLs (in the case of using an import library they are also assigned to local functions) - the linker is not involved in the procedure. Further information [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/about-dynamic-link-libraries).

Therefore I don't think that there was something "slightly wrong" in what I had posted above, and certainly not "literally everything".

As for whether my answer should be considered useful or not, I think I was right to suggest not creating an executable and changing it to a dll. An MFC DLL is a DLL "based on" (using) the MFC library - this was clear in my first post. The OP didn't ask about MFC extension DLLs particularly.

Comment: This is ever so slightly wrong (literally everything), and does nothing to address the question that was asked.

Comment: @IInspectable: Everything wrong? What exactly? Please comment, otherwise it would be unfair and void "criticism" (and I can't guess why, no matter how much I scratch my head). And my post actually not only answers the OP's question, I also took the pain to explain what an exe, a dll or MFC is, a matter for which the OP appears to need some clarifications.

Comment: Those entry points aren't entry points. A process is a container for resources. It need not hold any threads altogether. A DLL is called DLL because *linking* is done at run time. That enables dynamic loading, but that's not why a DLL is called DLL. And then, it ultimately evades the question: What is the difference (and for MFC DLL projects there are more differences than just the *"Configuration Type"*).

Comment: @IInspectable, I edited my post to include links to the documentation on the matters discussed. They prove that my post was NOT really wrong.

Comment: *"It's actually impossible to build an executable without a `main()/WinMain()` function"* - That's incorrect. Those aren't the entry points that wind up in the PE image. [It's just what the CRT calls](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573). If you aren't using the CRT then you are free to use any symbol for the entry point.

Comment: *"As for DLLs, the term dynamic "linking" is [...] not linking in the usual way, ie resolving externals, changing symbol names to addresses, performing fixups and the like."* - Indeed, that's *exactly* what's happening, when a DLL is loaded. Once loaded at its final base address the addresses of exports are known, and the importing module's IAT entries are overwritten with those addresses. Likewise, the DLL will have *its* imports resolved. Clearly, a DLL can have imports. You wouldn't be able to dynamically link against the CRT otherwise (which you always want).

Comment: So yes, it is called "linking" because that's what it is. It's just not done by a tool (e.g. `link.exe`) but rather the OS' loader implementation. As always, Raymond Chen has written several insightful blog entries on the topic. You can start with [Rethinking the way DLL exports are resolved for 32-bit Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060720-20/?p=30453) and keep going.

Comment: Concerning the claim, that every process **must** have at least one thread of execution, that's not accurate either. A process *object* can have zero threads, and we're making use of that literally all the time (e.g. `CreateProcessW(...); WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, ...);` - at that point there aren't any threads anymore, yet the process object is still live, as evidenced by the ability to call [`GetExitCodeProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess)).